# interactjs - save responsive position

Tags: html, css, responsive, interact.js

I'm creating a form builder and I'm using `interact.js` to move elements and change their size. The problem is that when I drag them the design is not responsive anymore. This is the code of the function that is fired on `dragmove` event:

```
function dragMoveListener (event) {
  var target = event.target,
    // keep the dragged position in the data-x/data-y attributes
    x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx,
    y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy

  console.log($(target).parent().attr('id'))
  // translate the element
  target.style.webkitTransform = target.style.transform
                               = 'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)'
  // update the posiion attributes
  target.setAttribute('data-x', x)
  target.setAttribute('data-y', y)
}
```

I tried to use `percentages` and `em` but it didn't work. I'm really stuck and I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

Comment: Use left-top  instead of translate(x,y) and  use left-top with % relative to it's parent div.